# How to solve a polynomial equation with genetic algorithms in java?

Tags: java, genetic-algorithm, polynomial-math

For my first class project I need to understand the basics of how genetic algorithms work (no big deal), I also need to find an example of a number optimization problem which is solved by using genetic algorithms in Java, and be able to explain how it works to my Professor.

I have searched the internet the best I can to find a Java program that solves some form of a multi-variable equation with constraints, but to no avail.

So my question is: Does anyone happen to have linkable content to a sample polynomial solving GA with constraints?

Comment: Is it absolutely necessary that it is programmed in java or are you comfortable with C# as well?

Comment: I was instructed that it should be in a programming language I know, which unfortunately the one I know best is Java, though I do believe C# is similar? I'd be more than willing to check a c# example out.

Comment: Have you looked at metaheuristic optimization frameworks like [ECJ](http://cs.gmu.edu/~eclab/projects/ecj/) or [HeuristicLab](http://dev.heuristiclab.com)? I don't know if your particular polynomial is implemented, but I assume the solution approach is similar to another real-valued function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JGAP is a Java framework for GA and GP and provides GA+GP examples for solving formulae. Please see http://jgap.sf.net